# Error projecting high dimensional vector into lower dimension

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I want to project a vector of dimension 7 into a vector of dimension 3. I am using the PCA method:

```
double c[3][7] = { { 20614.520325,  14429.227642,  14319.951220,  14700.390244,  17404.300813,  13451.105691,  12444.788618 }, { 19054.388889,  13578.222222,  14286.500000,  17277.305556,  17107.555556, 23428.361111,  15735.083333 }, { 14431.971429,  5051.971429,  7382.857143,  15523.428571,  4925.828571,  5575.457143,  5175.885714 } };

cv::Mat pcaset(3,7, CV_32FC1);

for (int i=0;i<pcaset.rows;i++)
{
 float* ptr = pcaset.ptr<float>(i);
 for (int j=0;j<pcaset.cols;j++)
 {
   *ptr++ = c[i][j];
 }     
}

cv::PCA pca(pcaset, // pass the data
    cv::Mat(), // we do not have a pre-computed mean vector,
           // so let the PCA engine to compute it
    cv::PCA::DATA_AS_ROW, // indicate that the vectors
                        // are stored as matrix rows
                        // (use PCA::DATA_AS_COL if the vectors are
                        // the matrix columns)
    3 // specify, how many principal components to retain
    );

cv::Mat p1 = pca.project(pcaset.row(1));
```

I have applied PCA over a matrix of data with 3 observations and 7 variables (3x7). Then, I have projected the first observation with its 7 variables into a lower space (3 dimensions).

However, when I get the 1x3 p1 vector, I get the following result: `-261082343354004313930203136.000000   0.000000   0.000000`. Which are values that seem wrong. What is my mistake?

Comment: (Note: That number is equal to `-7598496256221677 * 34359738368`, which is `- 0x1AFECAC62DE1ED * 2**35`).

Comment: What does that mean? @MaxLanghof

Comment: I don't know what that means. The reason I added this is because `261082343354004313930203136` has more digits than should fit into a `double` mantissa. But the decomposition I show is indeed a valid `double` representation (with `35` encoded in the exponent bits). I posted it because I was curious about it and maybe somebody else wondered about it too. Also, it could've been that some magic value becomes visible (e.g. for uninitialized memory). But as it stands I don't have any additional insight and can't help you with your problem though, sorry.